# Convert single-character string to char

Tags: c#, string, char, type-conversion

I need to convert single string character to `ASC` code, similar to Visual Basic `ASC("a")`
I need to do it in C#, something similar to `ToCharArray()`

```
("a").ToCharArray()
```

returns

```
{char[1]}
[0]: 97 'a'
```

I need to have 97 alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert a single character string to `char`, do this

```
char.Parse("a");
```

If you want to get char code do this

```
char.ConvertToUtf32("a", 0);  // return 97
```

Answer (score 6):

A string is an array of `char`, so you can get the first character using array indexing syntax, and a `char`, if used as an `int` (which is an implicit conversion), will return the ASCII value.

Try:

```
int num = "a"[0];   // num will be 97

// Which is the same as using a char directly to get the int value:
int num = 'a';      // num will be 97
```

---

What you're seeing that seems to be causing some confusion is how the `char` type is represented in the debugger: both the character and the int value are shown.

Here's an example of an `int` and a `char` in the debugger as well as in the console window (which is their `ToString()` representation):

```
int num = "a"[0];
char chr = "a"[0];

Console.WriteLine($"num = {num}");
Console.WriteLine($"chr = {chr}");
```

[image]

Comment: If `a` is a known constant (hardcoded), then you can use the single apostrophe to denote the `char` type. e.g. `int num = 'a';`

Answer (score 1):

char chrReadLetter;

chrReadLetter = (char)char.ConvertToUtf32(txtTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1), 0);

Reads the first letter of the textbox into a character variable.